# Skip Header when converting BizTalk CSV to XML (After Generating Schema)

Tags: xml, csv, xsd, schema, biztalk

I used the flat file wizard to generate my schema, all is working fine, except I don't want the header in my XML.

Seems like I should be able to change one property in the schema and make it work, but I've been looking and can't find the right property (and is it on the schema, the root element, or the repeating group?)  Looking for something like "CSVContainsHeader" true/false.

The first part of my schema looks like this:

```
- <xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <xs:annotation>
- <xs:appinfo>
  <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" /> 
  <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char="" pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="inventory_items" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
- <xs:element name="inventory_items">
- <xs:annotation>
- <xs:appinfo>
  <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
- <xs:annotation>
- <xs:appinfo>
  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
- <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="item">
- <xs:annotation>
- <xs:appinfo>
  <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="," child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
```

Comment: Is the "inventory_items" your header? If you define both your header/body in same schema,  I don't think you can "ignore" the header cause it will make the message invalid.

Comment: Didn't have header in the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to have the flat file disassembler completely ignore the header content, but there are a few ways you can achieve your goal.

The easiest is to just make a record or element in your schema be the 'Header' element, and ignore it in your mapping.  This is probably the most straightforward approach, even if it's annoying to have a record/field element/attribute in there that you don't use.

You could also create a separate header schema, and then set the "Preserve Header" property to false on the flat file disassembler.  This is really just a more involved way of doing the same as above, but the schema you work with won't show the header data while you're mapping.

Finally, you could create a schema for an instance of the document that has no header, and then write a custom pipeline component to remove the header line from the incoming message in the decode stage.  While this would technically work, I can't say I'd recommend introducing this additional dependency to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks, so if I don't even have a map, is #1 out, or I would have to create a dummy map?  The whole project is just to convert a SQL extract CSV to XML. The SQL was built only for this purposes, so everything matches exactly (no map was needed). I remember now using method #2, but more for output CSVs.

Comment: Added the map.  Been doing BizTalk 10 years, but CSV's come and go from client to client.  Wish BizTalk had an auto-drop-header feature.  So I added a Header record (Child delimeter set to "," , with 5 dummy columns, one for each real column, Min/Max occurs=1).  I then created the new map, seemed slightly easier than creating the second schema. Works fine.  Thanks

Comment: Good to hear.  If you don't need a map, then you don't need a map - you could just leave the headers in your dummy element, or you could use the two schema method and ignore the header schema in your output.